# Dropdown button with form-control class in Boostrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu

I am quite confused about the form-control class in Bootstrap 3.
Adding the form-control class to a simple button makes it appear with a width of 100% on smaller devices.

How can I achieve the same effect for the dropdown buttons?

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Adding the form control to the btn-group, the button, both or wrapping it with a from-group makes no difference. Nothing happens :/ Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think these adjustments could be done without touching the css. First, a "form-control" class should apply to the button only, and afterwards it doesn't stretch due to the wrapping div.btn-group inline-block property.

so we have to add a display:block triggering class for small resolutions, which is "col-xs-12".

and for bigger screen it's necessary to manually reset this display back to inline-block in a media query.

http://jsfiddle.net/EuHm5/

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .btn-group.col-xs-12 {
    display:inline-block;    
    width:auto;  
  }
}
```